# Ye olde Pipe Flow Animation

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i try to script a flow-animation ( basic color, nothing fancy ) through a grid of "pipes".
( think of a 5*5 tiled screen) 
since the pipes are created completely dynamic at runtime, the animation has to be scripted also. 
At the moment it escapes my mind on how to do this in actionscript, without pre-generated masks.

thanks for all hints!

Answer (score 0):

You wish to visually 'simulate' the flow of some liquid (for instance water) through pipes in the same style that it is done in pipe games?

http://www.mclelun.com/img/blog/120411_pipe_02.jpg

Alright...

Are you willing to use bitmapData (pixel) to create this effect?

Here is how I would go about it..

create a short script to fill a rectangle (block) of pixels gradually..

ie

```
var animateOn  : Boolean = true;
var startPoint : Point = new Point(beginX , beginY); 
var endPoint   : Point = new Point(finishX, finishY);
var step : Number = 1 / Point.Distance(startPoint, endPoint);
var currentPos : Number = 0;
onEnterFrame(e : Event):void
{
   var p : point = Point.interpolate(startPoint, endPoint, currentPos);
   bitmap.drawRect(p.x - 2, p.y - 2, 4, 4, someColor);
   currentPos += step; 
}
```

This is just an example of the top of my head (will not compile)
The idea is to keep feeding in the right startPoint and endPoint for each tile..
You could easily animate it like with without using any mask.

You can define each type of tile as a vector of points and then iterate from one point to another by adding the position of the tile to each point.

Comment: hi, and thanks. however my problem are more the curved items ... i can calculate and draw a curve do be drawn dynamically, but to fill that is a little to difficult for me at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

To fill a curve dynamically you may want to use this closed formula for a Bezier curve:

```
//start point
var s = new Point(x0, y0);
//cont point
var c = new Point(x1, y1);
//end point
var e = new Point(x2, y2);

var step : Number = 1 / (Point.distance(startPoint, controlPoint) +  Point.distance(controlPoint, endPoint));
var t : Number = 0.0;

private function onEnterFrame(e : Event):void
{
    var p : Point = new Point();
    p.x = (s.x * (1-t) + c.x * t) * (1 - t) + (c.x * (1-t) + e.x * t) * t;
    //do the same for y axis
    drawSomething(p.x, p.y);
    t+= step;
}
```

this will animate a curve style flow

Comment: This is a very basic example - the step helps you time how many frames it will take for to complete the animation. Here I fixed it